# mysql query (insert) inside function unable to execute

Tags: mysql, function, insert

i have a function like this:

```
function record(){
$table = new table;
$clogin = new login;
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 
$ip =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
mysql_query("insert into log (player, date, ip, on) values ('$clogin->username', '$date', '$ip', '$uri')");
$fopen = fopen("data/log.txt", "a+");
fwrite ($fopen, "PLAYER: $clogin->username DATE: $date IP: $ip ON: $uri\n");
fclose ($fopen); }
```

I also have other mysql query inside another function and it's work. And the fopen, fwrite, and fclose also executed properly. i wonder, why in this function the query didn't work. am i wrong wrote the query?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? And yes, as Lukas points out, you are making yourself susceptible to SQL injections :)

Comment: no error reported.
i add another mysql_query (select) inside that function and its work properly.

but the insert didn't work.


which part make me susceptible to SQL injections? the $uri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the two fields of the table `LOG` are [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL (`DATE` and `ON`). Instead use back tick ( `` ` ``) before and after the field.

Like this one:

```
INSERT INTO `tableName`(`fieldA`,`fieldB`,`fieldB`) VALUES ('','','');
```

Comment: welcome. you have to accept this answer to let others know that your question has been answered.